# Strange behavior in Gerrit / Jenkins trigger "change merged" instantly merges

Tags: jenkins, merge, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have 2 verification triggers in Jenkins: "patchset created" and "change merged".

Before when someone in Gerrit clicked on "submit", then Gerrit delayed the merge until Jenkins responded SUCCESS. But now Gerrit merges instantly and in parallel Jenkins returns FAILURE later.

Do you know what I do wrong ?

Here is my .config:

```
[access]
inheritFrom = All-Projects

[access "refs/*"]
owner = group Project_Admins
forgeAuthor = group Project_Admins
forgeCommitter = group Project_Admins
push = deny group Project_Admins
push = +force group Project_Admins
pushTag = group Project_Admins
exclusiveGroupPermissions = push

[access "refs/heads/*"]
pushTag = +force group Project_Admins
label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project_Admins
label-Verified = -1..+1 group Project_Admins
submit = group Project_Admins
push = deny group Project_Admins
push = group Project_Admins

[access "refs/tags/*"]
push = +force group Project_Admins
push = +force group Project_Admins
pushTag = +force group Project_Admins
pushTag = +force group Project_Admins
create = group Project_Admins
create = group Project_Admins

[submit]
mergeContent = true
```

Comment: What changed in the Gerrit and / or Jenkins configuration to make this start happening ?  The Gerrit configuration is stored in git so it's easy to browse history; if the Jenkins job configuration changed, that's not so easy to track unless you have the Job Configuration History plugin.

Comment: I have feedback from our team in India and we've found out the following:
"We observed this behavior lately… and this is happening since Gerrit upgrade to v2.11.2. The earlier version 2.9.1 was not behaving so. I am yet to find a fix for this." It seems that this behavior has changed. I have browsed through git history of the configuration and could not see differences. I will keep all informed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue with the situation you've described. Actually when someone clicks on "**Submit**" button, the change is immediately merged. This is right. Gerrit always worked this way (in version 2.9.1, 2.11.2 or any version). I think there's something wrong with your question or maybe in some cases the changes were pending due to other changes dependence (not waiting for the Jenkins build).